# How to use UNION(concat/union) in Entity Framework with one call?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I need to do a UNION in Entity Framework but I need to do only one call to the DB. I know that I can use CONCAT/UNION but it calls the DB for each CONCAT/UNION, and thats not what I want. And I need to use TOP 4. It is too slow.

here is my example...

```
using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
         var query1 = "SELECT TOP 4 * FROM Products where CategoryID=1";
         var query2 = "SELECT TOP 4 * FROM Products where CategoryID=2";
         var query3 = "SELECT TOP 4 * FROM Products where CategoryID=3";
         IEnumerable<Product> p1 = db.Database.SqlQuery<Product>(query1);
         IEnumerable<Product> p2 = db.Database.SqlQuery<Product>(query2);
         IEnumerable<Product> p3 = db.Database.SqlQuery<Product>(query3);

         IEnumerable<Feed> all = p1.Union(p2).Union(p3);

        return all.ToList();
    }
```

how can I do a UNION with one call?

Comment: If you write raw sql query, why you just not make UNION in that same raw sql query? Just concatenate your query1, query2, query3 with " UNION " and run that query.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible using the `SqlQuery` method. You need one of the methods returning an `IQueryable`. You are calling `Enumerable.Union`, which EF doesn't know about.

Comment: Of course main question is _why_ you use raw sql for such simple queries.

Comment: Be wary of pure sql strings. Paramertize your strings using best practices.

Comment: @Evk, I tried to explain what I need in RAW Sql. I am trying to do it in EF.

Comment: Well then put what you really try in question, because its important. With EF queries what you are doing should work fine and result in one db call.

Comment: @Evk, they should, but they do not. See my question, which is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49597645/why-my-entity-framework-creates-several-queries-instead-of-a-single-union-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are bent in doing this using pure LINQ you could do a group by and then top 4 on the values within the group.

```
  var result = db.Products.GroupBy(p => p.CategoryID).SelectMany(g => g.Take(4));
```

if you are ok with two lines you could also use a compiled query:

```
var query = CompiledQuery.Compile<ApplicationDbContext, int, int, IQueryable<Product>>(( ctx, filter, top) => ctx.Products.Where(p => p.CategoryID == filter).Take(top));
var result = query(db, 1, 4).ToList().Union(query(db, 2, 4).ToList()).Union(query(db, 3, 4).ToList()).ToList();
```

This one will generate 3 roundtrips to the database but still return only max 12 records (not as good as the groupby option in my opinion).

Comment: hi, that looks great. but Products will get all the products from DB abd it will Take(4). So this is not very fast

Comment: LINQ will translate this to a set based operation and most of the work will be done by the DB. Very little data will be transferred over the wire (depending on the size of your table of course). Try this with LINQPAD for instance and look at the SQL result.

Comment: it gives the correct answer but it returns all Products first, then applies Take(4).

Comment: If Products is a navigation property out of some other object (or an in memory list) then what is happening is that by invoking .Products you are asking EF to load the records in memory. If Products is an entity out of ApplicationDbContext then what you say is a bit puzzling to me.

Comment: It also depends on the version of EF. EF Core has not implemented GroupBy sql translation yet.