# Why my Entity Framework creates several queries instead of a single UNION query?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

I use Entity Framework Core 2.0.1.
In my EF query I need to combine several simple queries into a single UNION query. So, for a very basic example, I have a couple of similar queries

```
using (var dbc = new ItemsDbContext("some-connection-string"))
{
    var q1 = dbc.Items.Where(a => a.ItemType == "A");
    var q2 = dbc.Items.Where(a => a.ItemType == "B");

    var myList = q1.Union(q2).ToList();
}
```

I would like such SQL statement to be executed, as a single query, against my SQL Server database:

```
SELECT I.*
    FROM [dbo].[Items]
    WHERE I.ItemType = N'A'
UNION
SELECT I.*
    FROM [dbo].[Items]
    WHERE I.ItemType = N'B'
```

However, as much as I see in SQL Server Profiler, two separate queries are executed:

Query 1:

```
SELECT I.*
    FROM [dbo].[Items]
    WHERE I.ItemType = N'A'
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT I.*
    FROM [dbo].[Items]
    WHERE I.ItemType = N'B'
```

Result of this two separate queries is later union'ed by Entity Framework. But it is done in the calling code, not on SQL Server's side.

How can I make Entity Framework Core generate UNION instead of several queries?

Comment: can you try something like this, add your where clause
 var query = (from x in db.Table1 select new {A = x.A, B = x.B})
    .Concat( from y in db.Table2 select new {A = y.A, B = y.B} );

Comment: Tried using q1.Concat(q2) instead of q1.Union(q2) - same negative result: 2 separate queries.

Comment: q1.Concat(q2) instead of q1.Union(q2) both are same in this case, AFIK, when you are declaring variable in q1 and q2, they are asquerable and when you try to .Concat or .Union, it is resolving each one by one, you need to try with whole query as I mentioned above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/6812) server-side UNION is simply not implemented yet in EF Core 2.0.1.
Server-side UNION is planned to be implemented in EF Core v. 2.1, till then EF will perform local Union (in memory).

Comment: This has been bumped into being considered for the EF Core 3.0 release. However, it seems like the EF Core liaison in the thread is implying that we ought not to keep our hopes up.

Comment: It's supported now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54663722/does-entity-framework-core-support-union#comment107469845_55395584

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in Linqpad

```
     from x in 
     (from x in TableA select new {A = x.Code, B = x.Name})
    .Concat( from y in TableB select new {A = y.Code, B = y.Name})
    select x
```

and below is generated SQL Query

```
SELECT [t2].[Code] AS [A], [t2].[Name] AS [B]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[Code], [t0].[Name]
    FROM [coa].[TableA] AS [t0]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [t1].[Code], [t1].[Name]
    FROM [coa].[TableB] AS [t1]
    ) AS [t2]
```

Comment: How do you do it in LINQPad? I try it in live project, still same result: separate queries. Maybe the difference is that you use different tables (TableA and TableB), while I use only Items table.

Comment: Can it be that you use Linq to Entities instead of EF?

Comment: Can you give me a tip: what are you doing differently? Is it wrapping a query in another query? Or is it building of anonymous object what helps? I try different approaches, but still cannot get UNION in SQL :/

Comment: The shape of the generated query looks more like from LINQ to SQL. Hence has nothing in common with the OP issue.