# Does Entity Framework Core support Union?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I am trying to query multiple tables in EF Core using union as below, but it does not allow. Please find the query and also attached the image on the error hint that .net core frame work provides.

```
 var query =
                _context.Brand.Select(x => new { BrandID = x.Brandid })
                    .Union(_context.Factory.Select(x => new { Fa = x.Factorycode }))
                    .Union(_context.Brandfactory.Select(x => new { BrFc = x.Factoryid }));
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PishS.png)

Comment: You should provide the error message text directly here, not just as an image link.

Answer (score 3):

You try to have `Union` of different anonymous types, please use same types or don't use anonymous types at all, like in my snippet

```cs
var query =
                _context.Brand.Select(x => x.Brandid)
                    .Union(_context.Factory.Select(x => x.Factorycode))
                    .Union(_context.Brandfactory.Select(x => x.Factoryid));
```

Please also remember that EF core don't evaluate yet `Union` on database site, it will be evaluated locally. [More details in this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/6812)

Comment: Since EF Core 3.0 `Union()` [is now supported](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-3-0-preview-7-and-entity-framework-6-3-preview-7/) along with `Concat()`, `Intersect()`, and `Except()`. From what I already tried it is translated to inner join. Keep in mind that it will for work for the same type.